# Как выполнить повторное подключение к FTP?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ftp

Нужно подключиться по FTP из локальной сети с нескольких компьютеров, но сервер возвращает ошибку:

> 421 too many connections of ip addr

И мне нужно повторное подключение до тех пор, пока ошибка не уйдёт.

Или есть другие способы устранения данной проблемы?

Я пытался поймать исключение для повторной попытки подключения:

```
while True:  
    try:
       from ftplib import FTP 

       ftp = FTP('myserver')
       ftp.login('mylogin', 'mypass')

    except Exception:
       print('wait')

       ftp.close()
       time.sleep(1)
```

Что я делаю неправильно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для начала можно воспользоваться менеджером контекста `with` вместо городить `try except`:

```
from ftplib import FTP

with FTP('myserver') as ftp:
    ftp.login('mylogin', 'mypass')
```

и не заворачивать все в `while True:`, т.к. после удачного соединения ваш код пытается соединиться вновь...

Comment: Спасибо,но как организовать повтор при ошибке?

Comment: ftp.login() возвращает код подключения и текст